# How to find all users who have say Select grants on a Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am able to find all grants provided to a user but not for all users for a table . like TOAD shows under grants tab in the Table Describe window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the below tables:

```
select * from USER_ROLE_PRIVS;
select * from USER_TAB_PRIVS;
select * from USER_SYS_PRIVS;
```

Also check this [**script** which finds user who has previleges](http://www.petefinnigan.com/who_has_priv.sql).

> **Description :** Use this script to find which users have been granted
>   the  privilege passed in. The script checks hierarchically for each
>   user granted the privileges via a role.
>
> The output can be directed to either the screen via dbms_output or to a file via utl_file. The method is decided at run time  by
>   choosing either 'S' for screen or 'F' for File. If File is chosen then
>   a filename and output directory are needed. The  output directory
>   needs to be enabled via utl_file_dir prior to 9iR2 and a directory
>   object after.